# Issue concerning dates sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues to filter dates in a ListObject, as some of them get well sorted and others don't at all.
What I want exactly is to filter dates, take the one that is the closest to today and put it in an other ListObject (basically, the tool I am creating is a database where all important events are stored and I want to send the most recent in a ListObject). For the moment, in order to try things, I just put the filtered date in the column to the right.
Here is the a quick screenshot to explain :
[image: First screenshot]
So what I am doing is that I get the first column data. If I get the same reference multiples times, it means I have multiple events and I am trying to sort it using this code :

```
Sub derniereDate()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRowS5 As Long
Dim lastDate As String


lastRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowS5 = Sheets(5).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

j = 1
For i = 5 To lastRowS5 Step 1
    lastDate = Format(Sheets(5).Range("M" & i), "MM/DD/YYYY")
    While Sheets(5).Range("A" & i) = Sheets(5).Range("A" & i + j)
        If lastDate < Sheets(5).Range("M" & i + j).Value Then
            lastDate = Sheets(5).Range("M" & i + j)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    If j <> 1 Then
        Sheets(5).Range("P" & i) = lastDate
    End If
    i = i + (j - 1)
    j = 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of a case where the sort doesn't work properly :
[image]

Excuse me for my English, thanks for help and staying up for more details if needed.

Comment: Why not use built in sorting with multiple keys? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I tried to use it but had the same results (pretty sure I used it badly too...). I am looking for some possible format errors right now.

Comment: Why are you comparing a date as text?

Comment: I feel so dumb, I corrected it this morning and forgot to save... didn't even looked at it. Thanks Ron ! I'll post the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub derniereDate()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRowS5 As Long
Dim lastDate As Date


lastRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowS5 = Sheets(5).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

j = 1
For i = 5 To lastRowS5 Step 1
    lastDate = Format(Sheets(5).Range("M" & i), "MM/DD/YYYY")
    While Sheets(5).Range("A" & i) = Sheets(5).Range("A" & i + j)
        If lastDate < Sheets(5).Range("M" & i + j).Value Then
            lastDate = Sheets(5).Range("M" & i + j)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    If j <> 1 Then
        Sheets(5).Range("P" & i) = lastDate
    End If
    i = i + (j - 1)
    j = 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Simply had to change lastDate type... Sorry for the useless post...